# fixed px padding in % width div

Tags: css, responsive-design, padding

The padding CSS style adds some padding to one or more sides of a DIV.
However it adds to the total width/height instead of occupying existing space.

My problem is that I have a DIV which has a % width but it needs padding measured in px.
The total width must stay at a very specific % there is no room for flexibility.

If both the padding and width needed to be % or PX it would not be a problem as all you need to do is subtract the total padding from the width.

what do i do in this case?

(note that I cant just calculate what the padding PX would be as a % because the page has a responsive design with 5 different screen sizes and for some of them the DIV can shrink as the browser is resized within the same width range)

Answer (score 0):

The `box-sizing` CSS property should do what you're looking for. It requires a vendor prefix to work in all browsers. The default value is `content-box` which calculates the overall box model dimensions by adding the predefined dims and any offsets, i.e. padding, but if you use `border-box` it should allow your defined dimensions to take over. This code will apply the `border-box` style to your entire DOM, which you might like more:

```
*, *:before, *:after {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Here's a great article on it: http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/